# How to resize a widget after it is selected from the widget menu

Tags: android-widget

I am creating a widget and I want to be able to have the user select the size of the widget in a menu during the configuration activity. My problem is that in the appwidget-provider meta data xml, the block size is already set before the configuration activity is already entered. I need to be able to reset the info of the widget, which contains the block size (minHeight, minWidth), without having to add separate widgets of different sizes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this. It is an Android limitation. Create several widgets with different sizes, name them like "YourWidget (small)", "YourWidget (large)", etc. Or "YourWidget 1x1" and "YourWidget 2x1". You'll need several nearly identical appwidget-provider xml...

Since you'll need also nearly identical provider and configuration classes, define a base classes with all needed code there, and then inherit from them, something like this:

public class WidgetProvider2x1 extends WidgetProvider {
    @Override
    int getWidgetStyle() {
        return WidgetProvider.WIDGET_STYLE_2x1;
    }}

call getWidgetStyle() in the base class when you need to know the size of your widget.